# Bash get first N non white space characters

Tags: regex, macos, awk, sed

I am trying to check if a certain line in a file is commented out (has // as the first non white space characters of the line). How can I do this in bash? I'm ok with using sed, awk, whatever as long as it comes standard on OS X.

I have tried:

```
grep textOnlyOnMyLine | cut -c 1-2 myFile.java
```

but this will pick up white spaces if white spaces are the first 2 characters of the line. Also this command seems to hang after outputting what it finds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use grep:

```
grep '^[[:blank:]]*//' *.java
```

To search for a particular line # you can use sed:

```
sed -n '3s|^[[:blank:]]*//|&|p' file
```

Comment: Great answer. The grep command was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

With `awk` you can get the lines that are comments with:

```
awk '/\s*\/\//' file
```

So it looks for `[spaces]` plus `//` in the line and then prints them.

In case you want to check a specifid word you can do:

```
awk '/\s*\/\// && NR==line_number' file
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello
// this is a coment
 // this is a coment

$ awk '/\s*\/\//' a
// this is a coment
 // this is a coment

$ awk '/\s*\/\// && NR==1' a
$

$ awk '/\s*\/\// && NR==2' a
// this is a coment
```

Comment: You should mention that the above is gawk-specific.